# Batch script cannot find lowest value

Tags: batch-file

When i input something it only outputs the last value and not the lowest

```
echo.
echo enter number
set temp=9999
set /p pirm=

        if "%pirm%" equ "" goto error

(for %%a in (%pirm%) do (

    if %temp% gtr %%a (
    set/a temp=%%a
    echo temp = %temp% , a = %%a
    pause>nul
    ) else (
    echo else
    )
))
echo Lowest number
echo %temp%

goto reset2
```

INPUT:

```
1 5 7 9 3 25 15
```

OUTPUT:

```
enter number
1 5 7 9 3 25 15
temp = 100 , a = 1
temp = 100 , a = 5
temp = 100 , a = 7
temp = 100 , a = 9
temp = 100 , a = 3
temp = 100 , a = 25
temp = 100 , a = 15
Lowest number
15
```

I am pretty new with batch script so i might make a simple syntax mistake

basically what I want to do is to take my input as an array, then check if the number is lower than the current minimum, if it is make it the new minimum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo.
echo enter number
set temp=9999
set /p pirm=

if "%pirm%" equ "" goto error

(for %%a in (%pirm%) do (

    if !temp! gtr %%a (
      set/a temp=%%a
      echo temp = !temp! , a = %%a
      pause>nul
    ) else (
      echo else
    )
))
echo Lowest number
echo %temp%
```